# 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: nginx, azure, static-files

I was told that I can serve static content (.pdf and .docx documents) from Azure. First I have tried to get list of my PDFs from this "Blob SAS URL" link:

`GET https://testtestsitweu.blob.core.windows.net/publicfiles?sp=rl&st=2024-02-15T14:18:59Z&se=2025-02-15T22:18:59Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=TxAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaagU%3D`

But it gives me the following error even though it has "list" and "read" rights:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:b5d14821-701e-0083-2939-6363a8000000
Time:2024-02-19T13:42:06.9875994Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was rl
2024-02-15T14:18:59Z
2025-02-15T22:18:59Z
/blob/testtest/$root


https
2022-11-02
c






</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

What I am doing wrong here? Why it asks for authorization header? What is that? Why I would need an authorization header if I want to serve static content in the public web? I am using the wrong tool?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1153964/how-i-can-add-get-query-parameters-to-an-nginx-proxy - this question is a duplicate of the linked one, and the linked one provides a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if pdf is supported for static content

> You can serve static content (HTML, CSS, >JavaScript, and image files) directly from a storage container named $web

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Comment: Sure you can. Azure Blob storage doesn't really care about content. The error message is because of an invalid signature.