# How I can add GET query parameters to an Nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx, azure

I have PDF files in Azure. The links are like: `https://testtestsitweu.blob.core.windows.net/publicfiles/MyTest/doc.pdf?sp=rl&st=2024-02-15T14:18:59Z&se=2025-02-15T22:18:59Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=TxTaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaNgU%3D`

I have also a reverse proxy in Nginx:

```
location /documents {
    rewrite ^ /?sp=rl&st=2024-02-15T14:18:59Z&se=2025-02-15T22:18:59Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=TxTOjuaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaNgU%3D break;
    proxy_pass https://testtestsitweu.blob.core.windows.net/publicfiles/;
    proxy_ssl_name testtestsitweu.blob.core.windows.net;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

And when I visit `http://localhost:4200/documents/MyTest/doc.pdf` I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:e35abf59-601e-0054-5007-64329d000000
Time:2024-02-20T14:16:14.0631577Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>The specified signed resource is not allowed for the this resource level</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

I think it doesn't forward my GET parameters. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you generate the signature? Furthermore, this is generally not how you'd use blob storage. Generally you'd get the content directly from there, not proxy it. Either have a blob storage that doesn't require authentication, or have your software provide a signed URL for the client.

Comment: @vidarlo, someone else has generated it. Unfortunatly I don't know the details.

Comment: A signature is only valid for the *exact* URL for which it was made. Have you verified that the link works directly in a browser?

Comment: @vidarlo, yes, I can download the document from the browser with that link.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to do what you're doing. You have to pay twice for bandwidth if you do it this way - once for Azure and once for whatever service you use for hosting nginx.

Generally the reason for using blob storage would be that you don't have to care about the storage or bandwidth. You can focus on dynamic content.

Typically you would either have a blob storage that [allow anonymous access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal), or have your [web app sign and provide signed URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples) directly to the client.

Proxying via nginx just takes longer time and costs you more. In addition your idea will not work, because the *entire* URL has to be signed - e.g. `esttestsitweu.blob.core.windows.net/publicfiles/MyTest/doc.pdf?sp=rl&st=2024-02-15T14:18:59Z&se=2025-02-15T22:18:59Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c` which essentially means you need to sign dynamically based on the URL. You can't have a static append.

You should also read the [excellent answer you got over at SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021236/403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value-of-authorizat) which explains some of the aspects.

Answer (score -1):

I found an docker image for a nginx proxy to cloud storage accounts and here is an example config for an azure storage account

```
location / {
            proxy_set_header        Host {{ .Env.AZ_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}.blob.core.windows.net;
            proxy_set_header        Cookie "";
            proxy_set_header        Authorization "";
            proxy_set_header        Connection "";
            proxy_hide_header       x-guploader-uploadid;
            proxy_hide_header       x-xss-protection;
            proxy_hide_header       accept-ranges;
            proxy_hide_header       alternate-protocol;
            proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
            proxy_hide_header       Expires;
            proxy_hide_header       Cache-Control;
            proxy_ignore_headers    Set-Cookie;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_intercept_errors  on;
            proxy_method            GET;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;

            proxy_ignore_headers    Expires Cache-Control;
            proxy_cache             cloud-storage;
            proxy_cache_key         "$host/$proxy_host$uri";
            proxy_cache_valid       200 1d;
            add_header              X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

            {{ if eq .Env.NOT_FOUND_MEANS_INDEX "true" }}
            error_page              404 =200 /index.html;
            {{ end }}
            # $uri is appended to proxy pass automatically, starting slash (as in location) is peeled off
            proxy_pass              {{ template "proxy_protocol" . }}://cloud-storage/{{ .Env.AZ_STORAGE_BLOB_URL }};
        }
```

This uses the variables

```
docker run -d \
 -e AZ_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME="[account-name]" \
 -e AZ_STORAGE_BLOB_URL="[container/blob]" \
 -p 8080:8080 seediacity/nginx-storage-proxy
```

https://github.com/seediacity/docker-nginx-storage-proxy

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to append a string - or how to generate a HMAC signature.

Comment: It does answer how to include the get `proxy_method            GET;`

Comment: That's not the question.

Comment: What am I missing when he asks "I think it doesn't forward my GET parameters. What I am doing wrong here?"

Comment: He wants to add a get parameter to the request, e.g. `http://example.com/foo.pdf`to `http://bar.example.org/foo.pdf?get-parameters`. Your proposed solution does not add a querystring.